# Do I have a content search webpart in SP2013 Standard licence?

Tags: 2013

I am using SP2013 with standard licence. I would like to use the Content Search webpart. Is it possible or do I need to have the enterprice licence? I am talking about the search webpart where I can select many display templates.

These are the only search webparts I have.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an Enterprise webpart, so no. For standard you can use the Search Results webpart but as you may know, it works a bit different

Comment: Is it possible to create my own display template and use it for my search result webpart?

Comment: Read here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/change-settings-for-the-search-results-web-part-HA103998057.aspx#_Toc349550196

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need the enterprise license for the content search web part as it is not available to the foundation nor the standard edition.

See this blog for a comparison chart of all the SharePoint 2013 editions.

[SharePoint 2013 feature comparison chart all editions](http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/#SER)